# How to know what the error is when I use subprocess.run() in python with exception?

Tags: python

I am converting bash code to python.

I use mkdir of bash through subprocess.run() in python.

In the following example, subprocess.run() raise an exception.

However I could not check what the error is because I could not
get an resultant object returned by subprocess.run().

Are there any smart ways to know what the error was?
 Or should not I use 'try exception' here?

```
import sys
import subprocess

directory = '/tmp/test_dir'
options = ''

try:

    result=subprocess.run(['mkdir', options, directory], check=True)

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:

    print("In this example, subprocess.run() above raise an exception CalledProcessError.")
    # print("I would like to check result.returncode = {0}. But it failed because object 'result' is not defined.".format(result.returncode))

except Exception as ex:

    sys.stderr.write("This must not happen.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: just print the actual exception you caught `print(ex)`

Comment: why not just use `os.makedir` of python instead of creating a subprocess :) ?

Comment: @salparadise: thank you for telling me the solution. It is what I wanted.

Comment: @tkhurana96: thank you for commenting. My original code is based on mkdir of bash. It accepts more type of options than os.mkdir. So I stick to mkdir of bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always do

```
import subprocess

# make the subprocess
pr = subprocess.Popen(['your', 'command', 'here'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# blocks until process finishes
out, err = pr.communicate() 

# check the return code
if pr.returncode != 0:
    sys.stderr.write("oh no")
```

Comment: thank you for answering it. Maybe I should not use subprocess with excepion even though it has an exception mechanism.